# Is "assign" the default setup of the @property compiler directive?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, properties

If I define an property and just do:

```
@property(nonatomic) UIButton* button;
```

then I think that it's an "assign" property. Is that correct?

Comment: You've asked several questions that are answered directly in Apple's documentation about properties; have you read http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17 ?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I should read that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is.

Comment: It's probably clearer to just include all the attributes, though.

Answer (score 8):

default values of property params are

assign, readwrite and "atomic" (there is no keyword "atomic". only nonatomic)